# Omitted question mark in quoted material

Tags: publications

How do I insert a question mark into a quotation that was omitted in the original material? For example, "Now we find that our land has unacceptable levels of contamination. Will it never stop[?]” Or "...Will it never stop"?

Comment: Is this a scientific publication or literature?

Comment: Are you sure there needs to be one? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18380/should-sentences-like-i-wonder-end-with-a-question-mark

Answer (score 1):

How about: "Now we find that our land has unacceptable levels of contamination. Will it never stop” [sic]. This indicates that the error was in the original and the quote is exact.

See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sic, the first definition here.